# How to close multiple windows using expose/mission control on macOS?

Tags: macos, automation, mission-control

**Version: Mojave, 0.14.5**

When i swipe up on trackpad, I see a bunch of duplicate windows.

I want to close all except one.

[image]

Can I automate sequentially closing each other window?

Comment: If you’re using moom already that’s awesome. Please edit into the body of the question your  macOS and moom version if they are key to your challenge.